# HTTP GET request for range of Bytes in C++

Tags: c++, sockets, http, get, request

I need to send a HTTP GET request to a server to retrieve the HTML page in range of bytes.
But sending the following request retrieves the whole page rather in bytes.
Code examples will also be good.

GET /~aruhela HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.cse.iitd.ernet.in\r\nRange: bytes=0-10\r\nUser-Agent: HTTPGET 1.1\r\n\r\n

Comment: `User-Agent: HTTP 1.1` Hm. Start with making a proper request without byte range, then do the range part.

Comment: Well! apologies for that . I have ediited the code .IT was typing error .

Answer (score 2):

If the server does not support byte ranges, it will ignore your `Range` header and send the entire file in a normal `200` response.  There is nothing you can do about that, just accept the file and move on.

If the server supports byte ranges, it will send the requested bytes in a `206` response, or it will send a `416` response if the range is not acceptable.

Either way, the presence of a `Accept-Ranges: bytes` header in any `GET` or `HEAD` response will tell you if the server allows bytes ranges on that requested resource.

If you want to check if a resource supports byte ranges without downloading it, use a `HEAD` request.

To resume a broken download from a previous `GET` request, you have to query the server using `HEAD`, or otherwise remember whether the earlier request had a `Accept-Ranges: bytes` response header, and act accordingly on subsequent `GET` requests.  You should also take the `ETag` response header into account, sending a `If-Match` request header with the last known ETag if one was provided, so you can detect if the resource has been modified between `GET` requests so you can start over from the beginning if needed.

Comment: SIr! I have already tried GET request to check if the server supports bytes ranges . And for the particular server i am trying it does. U may check the following response i got usng curl command on Linux.
 curl -I http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~aruhela/index.html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 Oct 2015 18:55:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Fri, 15 Aug 2014 17:03:32 GMT
ETag: "9ba472-995-500ae0048e917"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 2453
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html

Comment: That command line sends a `GET /~aruhela/index.html` request. That is not the same thing as the `GET /~aruhela` request shown in your question. Two different resources, one is a file, the other is a directory. Most web servers will send an HTML file when requesting a directory that has an `index` or `default` file in it. But maybe your server is not allowing byte ranges when requesting a directory, only when requesting a file directly. You did not show the actual response for the request you are having trouble with.

Comment: OK. Sir there is still some confusion going in my head.
Following are the responses which I am getting.

1) On this:- curl -I http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~aruhela
I am getting this:-
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sat, 24 Oct 2015 07:08:18 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Location: http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~aruhela/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Comment: 2)On this:- curl -I http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~aruhela/index.html
Iam getting this:-

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 24 Oct 2015 07:09:30 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Last-Modified: Fri, 15 Aug 2014 17:03:32 GMT
ETag: "9ba472-995-500ae0048e917"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 2453
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html

Comment: Doing either way i am getting whole page rather then bytes.

Comment: #1 is receiving an HTTP redirect to a new URL (I seriously doubt it is really redirecting to the same URL that was requested, as you have shown). The second is not. But either way, if the server returns a `Accept-Ranges: bytes` header, and you are sending a valid `Range` header, and the server is not honoring it, then the server is buggy. But I don't see your curl command lines asking for ranged downloads (via `-C` or `-H`), though.  Please edit your question to include your actual code and/or curl command lines, the exact requests being sent, and the exact responses being received.

Comment: Thankyou! sir! I have sucessfully received the ranges.